# Install Jupyter Notebook on Miniconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, miniconda

I installed **[Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)** and I'm trying to use **[Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)** with it but haven't been able to do so. After installing miniconda I ran the `jupyter notebook` command on my terminal and jupyter wasn't installed.

I went ahead and installed it with the `conda install jupyter`. However, I once again ran `jupyter notebook` on my terminal and got the following console error:

> Emilios-MacBook-Pro:documents emilioramirezeguia$ jupyter notebook
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/emilioramirezeguia/miniconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in 
>       from notebook.notebookapp import main
>     File "/Users/emilioramirezeguia/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 45, in 
>       ioloop.install()
>     File "/Users/emilioramirezeguia/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 210, in install
>       assert (not ioloop.IOLoop.initialized()) or \
>   **AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'**

[image: Console_Error]

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening there. It's possible that some packages have the wrong versions. Have you tried updating `conda`?

Comment: I have @daviewales ... I'm actually installing this for a **Codecademy** course. A few months ago I installed Python through [this guideline](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/setup-python) and until today installed **Microconda** through [this other one](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/install-python-data-analysis). I'm wondering if something may have overlapped. I might try uninstalling and reinstalling everything.

Comment: It looks like it's getting everything from miniconda, but it's hard to tell. Incidentally, you already had a version of Python pre-installed, because Macs come with Python. Uninstalling everything, then reinstalling just miniconda is probably the easiest way to go. However, you could also investigate creating a Python virtual environment with miniconda.

Comment: Sorry @daviewales, just realized I typed Microconda instead of *Miniconda*. Could you guide me through the quickest way to uninstall everything?

Comment: Your best bet is to search `uninstall miniconda` in Google. The original Python installer you had from a few months ago *may* have an uninstall option if you run it again. Otherwise, you'll have to search how to uninstall it as well.

Comment: I'm hesitant to tell you specifics, because I might miss something. But the screenshot above tells me that most of Miniconda is contained within `~/miniconda2`, so you could delete that directory. You will also need to fix up your PATH. Run `echo $PATH` in terminal to see it. Then try to find and delete the Miniconda lines in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. But please look up more detailed instructions to make sure you don't miss anything.

Comment: Okay @daviewales. I'll look into the suggestions you provided but will make sure to look up more detailed instructions before deleting anything. Thanks for helping out! =D

Answer (score 47):

This problem has just happened to me as well. My older anaconda environments seem to be working fine but the environments I have created today seem to have this exact issue which throws `AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'`.

It seems to be because of the latest release of `tornado==5.0` which released either today or yesterday. I reverted back to the last stable version i.e. `tornado==4.5.3` and it worked.

Here's the solution

```
pip uninstall tornado
pip install tornado==4.5.3
```

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks @nitred, that solved the problem. =D

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get my work done today because of this error. Ugh.

Comment: Thank you, Solved my problem! )

Comment: Solved it for me also. I used `conda remove tornado`, `conda install tornado=4.5.3`, then reinstalled other required pkgs. Good catch.

Comment: I was using Jupyter with `tornado 5.1`, it was working. Just today it showed the above mentioned error. I installed **tornado==4.5.3**, it is working again. So does anyone have any idea on why suddenly it stopped working?

Comment: I had the same problem with `tornado 5.1.1` and uninstalling it as recommended (and reinstalling an older version) worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Miniconda is OK but Anaconda is recommend.

I have the same issue and thanks Nitred give the right solution.

It seems that jupyter notebook does not support the tornado 5.0.  So downgrade as the following:

```
pip uninstall tornado
pip install tornado==4.5.3
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed matplotlib in python, and need jupyter working. The package will try to uninstall matplotlib if you uninstall tornado, unless you do a force. But I still need matplotlib, I need that. So I still need to force matplotlib to use the old version of tornado. Turns out I had two tornado versions, one installed by pip, other installed by conda.

Ultimately running these commands got jupyter and matplotlib working again:  (Ran it in the conda environment that was broken.)

```
conda remove tornado --force # keeps matplotlib
pip uninstall tornado
conda install tornado=4.5.3
```

I earlier had used pip to install tensorflow library, which I also need, and maybe it brought along the junky tornado v5, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You must simply try doing -

`conda install jupyterlab`

(Perhaps, *Anaconda* team have updated the command in recent years or so). Above command works well on Windows/Ubuntu.