# Can I install Anaconda over a broken Anaconda install on MacOS?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to run jupyter notebook, but the Mac I'm on has a messed up Anaconda environment. The old owner uninstalled some packages that I'd like to use-- jupyter notebook, pyzmq, etc.  I want to use jupyter notebook, but after I tried to reinstall those packages manually using:

```sh
pip install jupyter
pip install pyzmq
```

I get errors when I run: `jupyter notebook`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module> import notebook.notebookapp
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 40, in <module> ioloop.install()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 210, in install assert (not ioloop.IOLoop.initialized()) or \
AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'
```

Can I just reinstall Anaconda again (or do I have to uninstall anaconda somehow and install over a clean system)?

Comment: It's probably safest to uninstall and reinstall. But [uninstalling is pretty easy](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html?highlight=uninstall#uninstalling-anaconda-or-miniconda).

Comment: Also, while you're reinstalling, do you actually need to use Python 2.7? It's only a year and a half from going out of support, and it's already a second-class citizen with Jupyter/IPython and some other packages, so reinstall time may be a good time to migrate.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert -- yes, I do need Python 2.7 for now, working with older code on an old computer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answers in this post will address your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141525/install-jupyter-notebook-on-miniconda)

But, if you want to start over, I would suggest [removing anaconda completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos/42182997) and then installing miniconda.

After you've installed miniconda, you can use:
`conda install jupyter`
`conda install pyzmq`
`conda install WHATEVER_PACKAGE`

Comment: Thank you! I removed anaconda using rm -rf //anaconda

Comment: Then I was still getting the AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'  and it turned out I had to upgrade pyzmq,pip, and tornado.  See https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3407