# Jupyter Notebook error Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, traceback

I am new to programming but want to use the Jupyter Notebook tool. When I try to open it in Terminal (I use `~ usr$ jupyter notebook` command), an error shows up with the following message (taken from Terminal):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 45, in <module>
    ioloop.install()
  File "/Users/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 210, in install
    assert (not ioloop.IOLoop.initialized()) or \
AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I am just looking for the localhost to open Jupyter Notebook in my Chrome browser.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this issue on their github: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3407

Comment: Try opening Jupiter from the anaconda-navigator. if it's not working try to reinstall anaconda or read the user guide.

Comment: I think I answered this a while ago. You can find the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141525/install-jupyter-notebook-on-miniconda/49142898#49142898).

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all,

On top of what @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard or @nitred suggested, I finally made it work by updating all packages (instead of downgrading tornado). As I use conda to download all packages, just typed `conda update --all` and Jupyter Notebook worked. One of the updates was precisely the "tornado" package, so probably this did the trick.

Thanks again!